# Outlook always asks me to select profile, even after making the only one the default

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, google-sync

After trying to install [Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync), each time I start Outlook 2013 I get this message.

[image: choose profile]

Despite checking "set as default profile" it comes back each time. Is there anyway to get rid of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable this option in Control Panel. Follow these steps:

### Turn on or off profile prompt

1. Exit Outlook.
2. In Control Panel, click or double-click Mail (search Mail).

[image: Profile]

3. Click Show Profiles.

Under `When starting Microsoft Outlook, use this profile' , click Prompt for a profile to be used or **Always use this profile**.

[image: Tick]

This will disable the feature that always asks you to select a profile.